# Where is the cron information stored on my gentoo system?

Tags: cron, gentoo

I have a Linux gentoo system, which performs a cronjob every day at 3:10 in the morning. However, no file in `/etc` contains any related information to this particular cronjob, and the result of `crontab -l` is

```
# check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly and cron.monthly
MAILTO=""
0  *  * * * rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.hourly
1  3  * * * rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.daily
15 4  * * 6 rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.weekly
30 5  1 * * rm -f /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly
*/10 * * * * test -x /usr/sbin/run-crons && /usr/sbin/run-crons
```

The directory `/etc/cron.daily` probably contains the job in question, but for a time at 3:01! Why is that? Is the actual cronjobn stored somewhere else? Does it take gentoo 9 minutes to realize to execute a job?

Additional information:

- I have a different crontab job for 13:20 (in cron.d) which is executed exactly at 13:20 every day.

Comment: no idea about gentoo, but maybe the job is run under another user context? Look into /var/spool/cron/ , maybe you find something there.

Comment: Did not find something different there; I am looged in to the system as root.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's not from another user:

```
getent passwd | while read r; do sudo -u $(echo $r | cut -d':' -f1) crontab -l; done
```

Comment: No there isn't another user which has a cronjob at 3:10. If crontabs are defined, they are identical to the one I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -l` only lists the per-user crontab of the calling user. There is also a system crontab, which can only be edited by root but can run jobs as any users. The system crontab is in the file `/etc/crontab`, with additional jobs in files in the directory `/etc/cron.d`.

The directories `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and `/etc/cron.monthly` are not built into by cron, but traversed by a job listed in `/etc/crontab`.